# How can free token and aa pointer?

Tags: c

```
 char *token = NULL;
 char *aa = "<head>";
 token = strtok(server_reply, "\n");
 while (token) 
 {   
   token = strtok(NULL, "\n");  
   if(strstr(token,aa) !=NULL)
   {
    printf(token);
    free(token);
    free (aa);
   }    
 }
 getch();
 return 0;
```

How to free the pointer variables `aa` and `token`?

Comment: i m asking how to free memory ..what r u doing with main function

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/ strtok does not allocate any memory. it just returns a pointer to a location that is already there.

Comment: free(token);token=NULL;

Comment: Note that you skip the first `token`. If you want to search it as well, move `token = strtok(NULL, "\n");` at the end of the loop. And change `printf(token);` to `printf("%s", token);`. Also, remove those `free`s.

Comment: @Vinoth No. **Don't** `free`.

Comment: You don't free variables; you free objects. Specifically, objects you allocated with `malloc` (including indirectly, like with `calloc` or `realloc` or `strdup`).

Comment: if we remove free exception ih strstr.asm

Comment: anybudy know how we pARSING html data in c lang

Comment: @AnkitSahu You can use `sscanf` for parsing.

Comment: @AnkitSahu Are you sure that exception has anything to do with not `free`ing? My guess is that strtok returned NULL so you passed NULL to strstr.

Comment: how can u send me code for it

Comment: @Cool guy How to use sscanf  in parsing

Comment: not allowing to send full code that site

Comment: @AnkitSahu Depends on what you want to parse.

Answer (score 2):

In your code , you *never allocate memory* to `token` or `aa` , then why do you `free` them. Neither of functions you use allocate memory . So **no** need to `free` them .

And if you do try to `free` such , it will cause error in your program.

Comment: if i m not use free it also give an exception

Comment: @AnkitSahu Then you must have allocated somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Ankit what exception?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x6946da1e (msvcr100d.dll) in ff.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: @AnkitSahu Please post the full code. Consider posting a [mcve]

Comment: @AnkitSahu What do you mean by that? Do you get an error or something else when posting the code?